# C# Runtime compilation missing external project reference

Tags: c#, compilation, runtime

I have a solution in VS2013, the solution has 2 projects, projA and projB.

In projA, the startup project, I wrote some code to compile C# text files at runtime, and my code actually works well when linking it to namespaces inside of the projA running it.

But when I try to link it to namespaces inside of projB, for example doing something like `using namespaceInProjB`, it says that they dont exist. I thought they would also be found in the current domains assemblies?

Does anyone know how to include them as well? Here is my code:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();

        compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library";
        compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
        compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                        .GetAssemblies()
                        .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                        .Select(a => a.Location);

        foreach (string str in assemblies.ToArray<string>())
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(str);

        CompilerResults result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, scriptCode);

        // Write out all the errors
        if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
        { 
            errors = result.Errors;
            return null;
        }

        return result.CompiledAssembly;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure classes you use in `projB` are `public`, because by default classes are `internal` and you can't use them in another project in `projA` in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But my problem is not that the calsses are internal, I do use them in the native code of both projA and projB, its when the scripts get compiled at runtime that it tells me the namespaces dont exist.